# list iterators not compatible unordered_map

Tags: c++, c++11, dijkstra

I have a fairly large project that implements Dijkstra's algorithm to simulate a network sending packets I've run into an issue I have never seen before;

I have managed to narrow the problem down to this:

```
//Member function of vertex
unordered_map<Vertex *, int> getEdges()
{
    return _edges; //same data type as return type
}
//Call to member function 
Vertex *t = //Arbitrary vertex
unordered_map<Vertex*, int> edges = t->getEdges();
```

For some reason on the call to this function I receive the error 'list iterators not compatible'. Does anyone understand why this is happening?

EDIT: 
removed temporarily

EDIT2: 
Turns out I was getting an empty unordered_map back from getEdges() due to a last minute change I made. Apparently this can cause the 'list iterators not compatible'.

For the sake of other people learning from my mistakes i'll upload the code to a more permanent location in a bit.

Comment: That's a runtime error, right? Please include a minimal compilable example which actually demonstrates the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Yes it is a runtime error, I could zip the file/virus scan and link it to you.

Comment: @TheAnonyMoose1234512: No, Post here a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I should be able to copy post a tiny amount of code, run it, and get the exact same runtime error

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me in NetBeans, using C++ 11. Keep in mind the values I'm using are arbitrary, and of course I've hard coded every single Vertex to return arbitrary new edges (which I assume you'd change)..

```
using namespace std;
struct Vertex{

    //Member function of vertex
    unordered_map<Vertex*, int> getEdges()
    {
        unordered_map<Vertex*, int> v;

        std::pair<Vertex*, int> first (new Vertex(), 0);
        std::pair<Vertex*, int> second (new Vertex(), 1);
        std::pair<Vertex*, int> third (new Vertex(), 2);
        std::pair<Vertex*, int> fourth (new Vertex(), 3);
        v.insert(first);
        v.insert(second);
        v.insert(third);
        v.insert(fourth);
        return v; //same data type as return type
    }
};


int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{        
    Vertex t;

    //Call to member function 
    unordered_map<Vertex*, int> edges = t.getEdges();

    cout << "edges " << edges.size();

    // clean up
    edges.clear();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your clean up should at least delete `t`. (As `getEdge` implementation is a placeHolder, no remark on these one).

Comment: You misplace the delete, as you delete `nullptr` now... Simpler to change to `Vertex t;` btw and avoid manual memory management.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was getting an empty unordered_map back from getEdges() due to a last minute change I made. Apparently this can cause the 'list iterators not compatible'.

Comment: The minimal example I tried based on your question and my incorrect assumption that the error was detected by the compiler (obviously wrong, when I thought about it), did not present any runtime error even though an empty map was passed. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96a39ab6c93cbc07 .  So it's not just that the map is empty; there must be something else going on. This is why *minimal* compilable examples are useful, both for you and anyone helping.